# The Domain of the Expected Value Function?

Tags: probability, random-variable, terminology

One can write a function using the domain and codomain. For example, $f(x)=x^2$ can be written as $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_+$.

Can I express the expected value function using this way? For instance, $\mathrm{E}[X]$ is a function of $X$ and $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is the function of $\omega$.

$\mathrm{E}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ would not be the case since $X$ is not a real number. Is this $\mathrm{E}:\mathbb{R}^S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ if there are $S$ states in the sample space since $\mathrm{E}[X]=\sum_{s}{x_s}\mathrm{P}_s$? Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. $E[\cdot]$ is a linear operator (actually, a functional or integral operator), whose domain is the space of random variables $X$ and whose range is $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$. Note that $E[\cdot]$ must carry $P$, the probability measure on your space, i.e. $(\Omega,\sigma(\Omega),P)$. So really it's $E_P[\cdot]$, so that $E_P[X]:=\int_\Omega X(\omega)dP(\omega)$.

Digging in a bit deeper, the domain is the space of integrable measurable functions $X:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, with respect to $(\Omega,\sigma(\Omega),P)$. This is, in particular, a vector space.

Comment: This is basically right, but it's necessary to extend $\mathbb{R}$ to include $+\infty$ and you still have to exclude random variables with undefined expectation from the domain of $E_P$.  Alternatively, you could define $E$ on the space of essentially bounded random variables and then prolong it to the extent possible to other random variables by taking limits where they exist. (+1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I want to ask two more. First, can I write like this then? $\mathrm{E}_\mathrm{P}:(\Omega,\sigma(\Omega),\mathrm{P})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Second, is the space of random variables the same with the probability space? I think a random variable is defined on its probability space.

Comment: @JunyongKim: No, not really. $E_p$ is necessarily a map from random variables to $\mathbb{R}$, since $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a function.

Comment: Junyong, a fairly standard notation is to name the set of absolutely integrable functions something like $$L^1(\Omega,\mathfrak S,\mathbb P) = \{X: \Omega \to \mathbb R\mid \int_\Omega |X(\omega)|d\mathbb{P}(\omega) \lt \infty\}.$$This is often shortened to just $L^1(\Omega)$.Then you can say $$E:L^1(\Omega)\to\mathbb{R}.$$ $L^1(\Omega)$ is a real vector space under pointwise addition and scalar multiplication.  Thus $E$ can be viewed as a *linear function* on this space, thereby exhibiting it as an element of its *dual vector space* $E\in L^1(\Omega)^{*}$.